# Android Camera2/Camerax Super Macro Mode

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

Hi I am trying to develop an app which needs to take a photo of a very close item. I see there is a "Super Macro" mode in some phones. Could anyone let me know how to activate this mode in development? I have tried the `AF_MODE_MACRO`, but it is not good enough.

The attached screenshot shows the "Super Macro" mode.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This mode is probably not made available to regular apps by the manufacturer, unfortunately.  If AF_MODE_MACRO doesn't do it, then you'd have to information from the manufacturer and use a private API if they have one.